# Selecting all elements except one and its children/grandchildren

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to select all elements except one element and its descendant which might have children/grandchildren or even more.
What I exactly wanna do is something like...

```
$("*").not(".foo, .foo *").bind("touchmove",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this would disable all `touchmove`event except `foo`class and its children.
But unfortunately I don't know how many generations it would have because the code I'm about to
write would be used in alot of templates file so they might have no children at all or maybe they have 10 generations family.

is there any way to achive this? other than making new dev/span to wrap everyone else but the one I don't wanna select.(this solution would take really long time for some reason.)

any suggestion or recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/amUf2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3rd2w/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you want:

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/amUf2/5/)

Have you tried it? I made a small example with hover to make it visible + I selected only
div's and p's to make it easier, but it will work with all the elements as well.

```
$("div,p").not(".foo, .foo *").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "#70A5C9");
},function(){
    $(this).css("background", "#ffffff");
});
```

It works because every descendant inherits the classes of his ancestors. In my example you can see that the deepest div will have all the fooX class ( 1 < X < 6).

See another [visible example](http://jsfiddle.net/amUf2/7/), once I give foo3 a new background color, all the inner foos will have the same background color.

Comment: the point I got stack seems like the part of $("*"),I've already tested it and the code i wrote aint working properly.need I use specific tag for the first selector?

Comment: No, See here: http://jsfiddle.net/amUf2/10/ .Again, I selected all body descendants to make it easier with the background effect.

Comment: still doesnt work tho, title question was solved. thanks for answering

Comment: If you'll provide an example that does not work we can help identifying the problem.